Accessing Another Item Of a Schema From A Function In A Schema - Mongoose
I want to add a feature so users can make their email public but I don't want them to do that unless they verify their email address. for that, I have 2 keys, email.publicState for the User to Modify From Their Account Settings and email.isPublic that is used In The Server To Check If It Should Send The Email To The Client.
Code:
email: {
    verified: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
            validator: function(v) {
                // Regular expression for validating an email
                var re = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
                return (!v || !v.trim().length) || re.test(v);
            },
            message: 'Provided email is invalid.'
        }
    },
    publicState: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    isPublic: () => {return (this.email.publicState && this.email.verified)}
}

the isPublic function returns true if it should send the email to the client and false if it should not. the problem is that i think im doing this wrong because im getting the error Object is possibly 'undefined'. is there any way i can fix this? thanks
P.S. Im Using TypeScript
Edit: Im Now Using This Outside Of The user Schema but im still wondering if its right or not:
schema.methods.isPublic = function (): boolean {
    // WARNING -> ChatGPT Copy Pasted Code
    return this.email.publicState && this.email.verified;
};


Nothing wrong with schema.methods.isPublic. I would personally name it emailIsPublic but that's purely semantics. Your other option is to have isPublic just a simple boolean and set a validator that can't be true unless publicState and verified are also both true.
